# Eclipselink, @OneToMany does not work with schema-generation = drop-and-create

Tags: java, jpa, schema, eclipselink, one-to-many

After much research , I finally found the cause of failure.

With Eclipselink, `@OneToMany` does not work (return null) when `persistence.xml` contains:

**(drop-and-create)**

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
```

But it works well with this:

**(none)**

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
```

Here are all the code of the file `persistence.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" >
  <persistence-unit name="XXXX-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/xxxxDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="OFF"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="AUTO"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

P.S: `@OneToMany` works correctly with Hibernate.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by works correctly and does not work?  There isn't any information to say what is going wrong, and you haven't shown an entity or even mentioned if the problem is with the tables that get created or not.